# Firebase (AngularFire2) only allow OAuth login if user exists

Tags: firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'd like to use *only* the Google OAuth authentication within an Angular2 application using AngularFire2. However, when I sign in with Google, it automatically adds those credentials to the authentication/users area, even if that email address wasn't already there. What is the correct way to limit logging in to only existing users? Do I need to keep a separate collection of users and check against that? If so, do I run the normal login, then on the promise resolution, check to see if the user is in the users collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, it looks like, yes, a separate collection needs to be set up. I ended up adding it as follows:

```
{
  "appData": ...
  "otherAppData": ...
  "users": {
             "user@user%2Ecom": { "role": "admin" },
             "user2@user%2Ecom": { "role": "user" }
  }
}
```

By setting the email address (don't forget to escape the '.' since they can't be used as keys in firebase {[source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)}) it's easy to check if users/{email_address} exists.